# R 2.12.2 : sorting a date field in data.frame not working

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame that contains a date field and other information. I would like to sort it by date, but is never been successful. I am using R 2.12.2

Sample data :

```
   Name          Date          Position
    Ben        2010/02/01          HR
    Cat        2011/03/01          IT
    Dan        2009/09/23         Admin
```

Expected result :

```
  Name          Date          Position
  Dan        2009/09/23         Admin
  Ben        2010/02/01          HR
  Cat        2011/03/01          IT
```

I have tried following methods, but none of them are working correctly:

trial 1 :

> data_set = data_set[with(data_set, order(Date)),]

trial 2 :

> data_set[order(strptime(data_set$Date, format = "%Y%m%d")), ]

trial 3 :

> data_set = data_set[order(as.Date(data_set$Date, format="%d/%m/%Y")),]

trial 4 :

> data_set = data_set[with(data_set, order(as.Date(Date, "%Y-%m-%d"))),]

Kindly help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your trial 1 code of `data_set[with(data_set, order(Date)), ]` should work also.  If not, there may be a bigger issue.  You're trying all the right things.  It's most simply done in the second line below.

```
> data_set
##   Name       Date Position
## 1  Ben 2010/02/01       HR
## 2  Cat 2011/03/01       IT
## 3  Dan 2009/09/23    Admin
> data_set[order(data_set$Date), ]
##   Name       Date Position
## 3  Dan 2009/09/23    Admin
## 1  Ben 2010/02/01       HR
## 2  Cat 2011/03/01       IT
```

And if we decide we want to change the `class` to `Date` (which we should when working with dates), it should work just the same

```
> sapply(data_set, class)
##     Name     Date Position 
## "factor" "factor" "factor" 
> data_set$Date <- as.Date(data_set$Date)
> sapply(data_set, class)
##     Name     Date Position 
## "factor"   "Date" "factor" 
> data_set[order(data_set$Date), ]
##   Name       Date Position
## 3  Dan 2009-09-23    Admin
## 1  Ben 2010-02-01       HR
## 2  Cat 2011-03-01       IT
```

Comment: That only works because the dates are in numbers. It wouldn't work with a string like `Date <- c("10jun1960", "2apr1960", "30jan1960")`. You should always convert to `Date` or `POSIX` class when working with dates imo

Comment: They were actually factors.  I was making that edit as you commented. Thanks.

Comment: btw, the `order` function would work in this specific case, even if they were `character` class

Comment: Thank you for the comments and answers. After looking through code, i found out the issue is with my dataset, not the ordering function. Thank you for giving hints on this. ^_^